What's the best way to line up equals on a line of text?
I used the minipage environment to put the equation on the same line as the text. Is there any other way of doing this?
In addition, the line spacing is no longer respected, the preceding text is too high, I want to keep the line spacing, how can I do that too?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
Le périmètre d'un cercle.

L'aire d'un cercle.

L'aire $\mathcal{A}$ d'un disque de rayon $R$ est \begin{minipage}{3cm}
\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& \uppi \times R \times R\\
&=&\uppi\times R^2
\end{eqnarray*} \end{minipage}
\end{document}



Not related to the problem, but never use eqnarray environment for equations.

Can you tell me why?

@AndréC The eqnarray environment puts (large) spaces around the equals signs (or whatever you are aligning around), which makes the equation look quite different than it would without the alignment. The align environment and the aligned environment from amsmath are much, much better choices.

I wrote a summery article about eqnarray: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf

You can use aligned environment with t option:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek,amsmath}
\begin{document}
Le périmètre d'un cercle.

L'aire d'un cercle.

L'aire $\mathcal{A}$ d'un disque de rayon $R$ est
$\begin{aligned}[t]
A &= \uppi \times R \times R\\
&=\uppi\times R^2
\end{aligned}$
\end{document}



Thank you, how can we reduce the line spacing in the equations?

@AndréC - For example with the spreadlines environment of the mathtools package.

Great! Thank you so much!

This uses flalign*.  The first uses paragraph spacing, while the second uses equation spacing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Le périmètre d'un cercle.

L'aire d'un cercle.
\vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
\begin{flalign*}
\hspace{\parindent}&\text{L'aire $\mathcal{A}$ d'un disque de rayon $R$ est}&
A &= \uppi \times R \times R\\
&& &=\uppi\times R^2 &&% note the extra && at the end
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
&\text{Le périmètre d'un cercle.}& &&\\% note the extra && at the end
&\text{L'aire d'un cercle.} \\
&\text{L'aire $\mathcal{A}$ d'un disque de rayon $R$ est}&
A &= \uppi \times R \times R\\
&& &=\uppi\times R^2 
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}

